# How to combine vertically alignment and indentation

Tags: html, css

I want text to be in the middle when there it is a little text field, and when there is a lot of text I want an indent of 1 vmin around there
It doesn't work now. Example

```html
<p class="text">  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Cumque eaque provident natus exercitationem consequatur quo ab, ratione, accusantium voluptatum omnis veritatis nostrum. Quae iste mollitia quod magni necessitatibus ex placeat consequuntur reiciendis? Laborum eos molestias quibusdam consectetur provident ullam porro expedita pariatur ea enim autem minima aspernatur, praesentium tempora inventore atque eaque aliquam rerum et corporis. Incidunt, repellat! Fuga, in?</p>
<style>
.text{
  font-size: 2vmin;
  
  background: green;
    height: 20vmin;
  width: 20vmin;
  
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 1vmin;
  
  overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
  
  display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
</style>
```

the paddings from the top and a piece of text are ignored, although the bottom is ok how can I fix this
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem, you need to modify your HTML structure. In the code below, I did this:

1. Wrapped your `.text` paragraph in two `div` elements: `.text-outer-container` and `.text-inner-container`;
2. Removed your CSS rules from `.text` and applied it to `.text-outer-container`;
3. Applied `max-height: 100%;` to `.text-inner-container` (it impedes your text from appearing cut off);
4. Centralized the text inside the `.text` paragraph and added `margin-bottom: 3vmin` to replace the `.text-outer-container` bottom padding, which is not being respected because of overflowing.

That way, the text will be centralized in both axes, but its beginning will be limited to the text box.

```css
.text-outer-container {
  font-size: 2vmin;
  
  background: green;
  height: 20vmin;
  width: 20vmin;
  
  padding: 1vmin;
  
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
    
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.text-inner-container {
  max-height: 100%;
}

.text {
  margin: 0 0 1vmin;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-outer-container">
  <div class="text-inner-container">
    <p class="text">  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Cumque eaque provident natus exercitationem consequatur quo ab, ratione, accusantium voluptatum omnis veritatis nostrum. Quae iste mollitia quod magni necessitatibus ex placeat consequuntur reiciendis? Laborum eos molestias quibusdam consectetur provident ullam porro expedita pariatur ea enim autem minima aspernatur, praesentium tempora inventore atque eaque aliquam rerum et corporis. Incidunt, repellat! Fuga, in?</p>
  </div>
</div>
```